# Quitar url que se adjunta al generar un Pdf con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pdf

Estoy generando un pdf que toma un div y lo manda al pef, pero al momento de generarlo se le adjunta la url al pdf que se generó, y el número de pagina.

Cómo podría quitarselo

Asi es mi div

```
<div id="print-section">

                        <div id="goqrcode"
                            style=" width:200px;   margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;">
                            <h3 >{{nombre}} | {{item}}</h3></div>
                            
                    </div>
```

y así es mi js

```
print(): void {
    let vacio: string = null;
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=50%,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title></title>
          <style>
          .content {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
          }

          .img-content {
            flex: 1;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
          }

          .observation {
            height: 150px;
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;
          }
          </style>
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
  }
```

y así se ve el pdf, quiero que no se genere esa url dentro del pdf
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo creo que será mas fácil que generes el pdf directamente con alguna librería, yo por ejemplo uso [jspsf](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/), es muy simple de usar y solo te arroja lo que tu le pasas.

Comment: Es la impresión nativa del navegador. Deberías quitar la url directamente desde las configuraciones del navegador.

Comment: El problema con esa solución @Legna, es que el tiene que editar la configuración de el navegador en todos los equipos,  y al ser aplicación web no es funciónal

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea No era mi intención proveer una solución funcional. Simplemente señalar que es propio del navegador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias @Legna me dio una idea de porque salia, y encontre la manera de quitarlo desde el codigo y ya no desde la propiedad del navegador.

usando estas lineas

```
@page {
         size: auto;
         margin: 3;
      }
```